# What is scale and why do I have to reset it when using UIPinchGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to create a resizable face with UIPinchGestureRecognizer. All the tutorials online tell me to always reset the scale to 1, such as this code:

```
func changeScale(byReactingTo pinchRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
{
    switch pinchRecognizer.state {
    case .changed,.ended:
        scale *= pinchRecognizer.scale
        pinchRecognizer.scale = 1
    default:
        break
    } 
}
```

where scale is a CGFloat that is related to the size of the face.

However, I couldn't find any reasonable explanation as to why pinchRocgnizer.scale always must be reset to 1 after the user pinches. I understand that deleting it could cause erratic behavior, but why?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipinchgesturerecognizer/1622235-scale you can read the documentation. It is not the delta value so you should not concatenate.

Comment: @user2215977 But the documentation does not explain why pinchRecognizer.scale has to be reset every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation have said that the `scale` of `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` is calculated from the beginning of gesture recognition. In your code `scale *= pinchRecognizer.scale`, this is concatenating the value of `scale` in each invocation during the gesture.

If the value of `scale` is `1.1`, `1.2` then your `scale *= pinchRecognizer.scale` after the second invocation would be incorrect as its `1.32` not `1.2`. So if you change your code to `scale = pinchRecognizer.scale` you don't need to reset `scale` of `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to `zero`.

I guess the internal implementation of `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` is using the `scale` value to keep track of the relative `scale` of the `UIView` to the time the gesture being recognised. So if you reset it to `zero`, It means the `scale` is relative to the pervious invocation instead of the first invocation.